# Наилучшее решение для уникального идентификатора NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, ios, coredata

Доброго времени суток уважаемым форумчанам!

Корень вопроса идет из большого энтерпрайзного проекта на котором я проработал предыдущий год. Речь о большом iOS-клиенте со сложной бизнес-логикой и довольно развитой структуре данных и связей между ними, который изготовили мои предшественники. В качестве стореджа была избрана Core Data, транспорт с сервера - JSON. Для обеспечения уникальности объектов моими предшественниками было принято решение завести поле id c типом NSString для всех NSManagedObject-подлассов. Тип данного поля - [GUID](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) то есть строка формата:

> 6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF

Сейчас к сожалению не представляется возможным узнать почему именно этот формат идентификатора был принят на вооружение. Впоследствии (уже при мне) изготавливалась версия этого же клиента для Android, где использовался sqlite, дампы которого кидались при синхронизации с сервера на клиент и обратно. Коллега который занимался разработкой данного клиента уверял что переход с GUID'ов на обыкновенные числовые идентификаторы которые он применил (к сожалению не знаю точного формата) дали прирост к операциям по чтению и записи  в базу на более чем 20% в сравнении с GUID'ами. Сравнение на клиенте пожалуй было бы некорректным из-за специфики работы iOS-ного клиента через Core Dat'у, хотя в роли ее хранилища по умолчанию использовался тоже sqlite. 
Сейчас я продолжаю делать различные iOS-клиенты и хочется собственно узнать мнение бывалых:

**Какой формат данных вы считаете использовать наиболее удобным для идентификатора  NSManagedObject-объектов к которым предъявляются следующие условия:**

- уникальность
- быстрота чтения

По этому поводу есть такие мысли о недостатках распостраненных решений которые приходят в голову:

- GUID - достаточно уникальный для больших проектов но длинный к прочтению.
- хэш полей объекта - по сути тоже самое что и предыдущее решение. Потенциально проблемы с коллизиями на больших объемах.
- числовое значение (NSNumber) - неясно быстрее ли прочтение большого (например 8-значного числа) в сравнени с парсингом NSString как в предыдущих вариантах.
- автоинкрементное значение поля из базы сервера (скалярное значение на клиенте) - невозможность изготовить клиент без серверной базы. Где будут например клиенты, которые смогут меняться данными через облачный сервис, но не будут иметь никакого серверного API и хранилища данных на нем. Также непонятно будет ли это быстрее нежели использование NSNumber  из прошлого пункта.

Вопрос в последнем варианте в принципе и явился причиной описать тут мои размышления .Сейчас я делаю клиент без базы с облачным стореджем, где клиенты могут меняться друг с другом данными но не имеют общей базы на сервере, но решил не разбивать на два вопроса так как суть практически идентична. Большая просьба всех делиться использованными на проектах решениями и обнаруженными вследствие их преимуществами и недостатками, а также исправлениями моих убеждений по типам с аргументацией. Цель -  не найти серебрянную пулю, а научиться выбирать наиболее адекватное решение исходя из кондиций проекта на стадии проектирования.

Answer (score 2):

Для простоты сравнения по числам вы можете использовать не NSNumber, а int32_t, то есть **scalar properties for primitive data types**. 
Смотрел видео с WWDC 2013 по CoreData optimization, они рекомендуют использовать числа как идентификаторы если это возможно. К тому же обычно для фетча данных требует не только идентификатор. Числа и дополнительного набора параметров должно хватать для обеспечения уникальности, например:

```
NSArray *myProducts = [MyProduct findAllWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((shop == %@) && (uid == %d))", shop, uid];
```

в принципе обеспечит вам полную уникальность в поиске нужных сущностей

к тому же, с большим набором параметров для поиска вы можете использовать логику оптимизации предикатов, то есть ставить левее более сильные фильтры, которые проще в сравнении и отсекают больше данных сразу, в первую очередь. Скажем, в моем примере выгоднее при большом количнстве продуктов снача выбрать все из нужного магазина и уже в них искать по uid.

В одном из проектов приходилось использовать в качестве уникального идентификатора NSTimeInterval (также scalar property для NSDate) с точным timeStamp создания объекта, для той задачи это подходило, но сколь-нибудь изящным, конечно, не является.

У NSManagedObject есть свой objectID, который назначается объекту после его первого сохранения в базу.

Всегда нужно смотреть по конкретным задачам, но в большинстве случаев хватает обычно uid, заданного сервером.